# Mounting a drive in Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala)

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ubuntu-9.10

I have just installed Ubuntu on a machine that previously had XP installed on it. The machine has 2 HDD (hard disk drives). I opted to install Ubuntu completely over XP.

I am new to Linux, and I am still learning how to navigate the file structure. However, AFAICT, there is only one drive. I want to be able to store programs etc on the first drive, and store data (program output etc) on the second drive.

It appears Ubuntu is not aware that I have 2 drives (on XP, these were drives C and D).

1. How can I mount the second drive (ideally, I want to do this automatically on login, so that the drive is available to me whenever I login - withou manual intervention from me)
2. In XP, I could refer to files on a specific drive by prefixing with the drive letter (e.g. c:\foobar.cpp and d:\foobar.dat). I suspect the notation on ubuntu is different. How may I specify specific files on different drives?
3. Last but notbthe least (a bit unrelated to previous questions). This relates to directory structure again. I am a developer (C++ for desktops and PHP for websites), I want to install the following apps/ libraries.

   - i). Apache 2.2
   - ii). PHP 5.2.11
   - iii). MySQL (5.1)
   - iv). SVN
   - v). Netbeans
   - vi). C++ development tools (gcc, gdb, emacs etc)
   - vii). QT toolkit
   - viii). Some miscellaeous scientific software (e.g. www.r-project.org, www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

   I would be grateful if a someone can recommend a directory layout for these applications. Regarding development, I would also be grateful if someone could point out where to store my project and source files i.e:

   - (i) *.cpp, *.hpp, *.mak files for cpp projects
   - (ii) individual websites

   On my XP machine the layout for C++ dev was like this:

   - c:\dev\devtools            (common libs and headers etc)
   - c:\dev\workarea            (root folder for projects)
   - c:\dev\workarea\c++        (c++ projects)
   - c:\dev\workarea\websites   (web projects)

   I would like to create a similar folder structure on the linux machine, but its not clear whether to place these folders under /, /usr, /home or swomewhere else (there seems to be abffling number of choices, so I want to get it "right" first time - i.e having a directory structure that most developer use, so it is easier when communicating with other ubuntu/linux developers)

Comment: For reference, you questions about file locations are being answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/64033/linux-file-structure

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu **should** be reading your second partition automatically, all you would have to do to mount it is to click it from the menu bar. You'll need admin/root access to mount the drive the first time, but then it should be permanent until you either restart or unmount.

However, here's [helpful link to mounting NTFS drives](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Dapper#Windows) in Ubuntu. The same page also lists how to mount at startup, just scroll down a little.

Comment: I dont know if it is a terminology issue, but I dont think it a partition issue. Its a second *DRIVE* that I want to mount not a second partition on the same drive

Comment: No, it's perfectly valid to refer to the disk space on the second drive as a second partition. When you installed Ubuntu did you let it create a *single* partition for `/` on what used to be C:, or different partitions like `/home`, `/usr`, `/lib` ? It doesn't really matter: both methods are usable. Keep reading about Ubuntu and it will all start to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

1: Provide the contents of `/etc/fstab`. This should help getting some useful answers here.

2: Normally one wants to hide the details of what the physical layout of the drives is. [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard):

> /dev/     Essential devices, e.g.,
>   /dev/null.
>
> /etc/     Host-specific system-wide
>   configuration files (the name comes
>   from et cetera).
>
> /opt/     Optional application software
>   packages
>
> /usr/     Secondary hierarchy for
>   read-only user data; contains the
>   majority of (multi-)user utilities and
>   applications.
>
> /var/     Variable files—files whose
>   content is expected to continually
>   change during normal operation of the
>   system—such as logs, spool files, and
>   temporary e-mail files. Sometimes a
>   separate partition.
>
> /var/www/ Website file hierarchies
>   (the default location for websites
>   served by Apache).

3i-viii: The Synaptic Package Manager should have defaults that just work.

`c:\dev\`: `/dev/` is for physical DEVices. Since `/dev/` already has meaning different than developer something else is needed.

`c:\dev\`: To clearly distinguish the live development machines run-time file from the development files and to provide a networked shareable files I have seen a separate directory directly under `/` such as "Root Of Software Engineering", `/rose/`, for:  `c:\dev\workarea`, the source, temporary build files and the exported/deliverable results of the builds. It would have source code repositories. Individual developers would keep their working copies in the their home directory under `/home/`. When a work session is completed the files are placed back into the project directories under `/rose/`

The developer tools would be installed wherever the package manager normally puts them, the developer work results would be under something like `/rose/`, personal work in progress would be in the user's home directory under `/home/`.