# Linux file structure

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ok. I asked this question earlier(as part of another question) and got no response - so here it is again:

what i the recommened directory for me to store the following:

1). my apps
2). development tools (C++ tools)
3). AMP applications for LAMP stack (Apache, MySQL, PHP)
4). files for websites that I develop on my machine - e.g. website1, website2 etc ...

Answer (score 11):

1. Let your package manager handle it. (Your other question mentions you are using Ubuntu 9. Your package manager is Add/Remove programs in Ubuntu 9.04 or Software Center on 9.10. If you prefer the command line, you have a choice of apt-get or aptitude.) Most go in `/usr/bin`.
2. See above. Although, gcc and g++ are preinstalled on a lot of distros.
3. See 1.
4. `/var/www`

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, if your distribution uses a sane package manager, whatever it defaults to is probably where it's supposed to go.  For the most part, applications get thrown in the `/usr` heirarchy, with binaries in `/usr/bin`, libraries in `/usr/lib`, documentation in `/usr/doc`, and so on.  Configuration files like to show up in `/etc`, regardless of where their applications are installed.  Proprietary packages have a tendency to hide in `/opt` just to make things interesting.

A quick rundown on your specifics:

1. Apps tend to be installed in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or in some cases `/opt`.  If you're developing your own software, or custom modifying an existing package, `/usr/local/bin` is probably your best choice.  Otherwise, use your package manager's default.
2. Development tools should be treated the same as any other applications.  See 1.
3. Again, AMP applications should be treated the same as any other applications.  See 1.
4. `/var/www` is the most common, but `/srv/www` seems to be gaining momentum.  Depending on your system, the two may be symlinked together anyway.  You should probably use whichever one Apache defaults to for consistency.  User-specific webpages would go in `~/public_html` regardless.

Check out the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) if you want further details and rationale thereof.